# Sql Azure Premium - Importing dacpac error 'Origin.xml'

Tags: sql, azure, dacpac

I'm trying to import my database using an dacpac file to Sql Azure Premium Version and after some minutes I got this message:

"Error encountered during the service operation. Could not load package. 'Origin.xml' is missing from the dacpac package"

I did another import using an small database and work was okay.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite an old question but I just encountered the same issue. The problem was that .bacpac was exported with an old version of MSSMS and I tried to import with R2. Exporting with R2 solved the issue.